# Wordpress Локализация __()

Tags: php, wordpress, локализация

Проблема с локализацией. 
Вот пример кода

```
...
__("Value","my_app_domain");
....
__("Value","my_app_domain");
....
```

создал pot файл, там

```
#: my_plugin.php:95 my_plugin:145
msgid "Value"
msgstr ""
```

но переводится только первое значение... что я делаю не так?
может надо забить все переводы в массив и брать оттуда?

Comment: а *value* везде одинаковое? Если скопировать то, что переводится в то место, где не переводится - все так же остается? Если не переводится, то попробуйте вставить то, что переводится, два раза (т.е. то, что переводится и еще раз его же)

Comment: @BOPOH  , Вставил так __("Value","my_app_domain") ." ". __("Value","my_app_domain"); и все работает, но потом скопировал в нужное место и там уже не работает(там другая функция уже идет)

Comment: А там, где не работает, там вообще хоть что-нибудь переводится?

Comment: хмм... там только это... надо попробовать добавит еще что-то, сейчас попробую и отпишу)

Comment: там где не работает - там может еще толком ничего не загрузилось (т.е. язык), потому по дефолту и отображает (т.е. считает что именно это и надо отображать)

Comment: да... именно там и не работает... попробую переделать. спасибо за помощь)